# How do I make rounded Jquery UI tooltips?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, stylesheet

This is the css in my stylesheet. Weather I use ui-tooltip or make my own custom tooltip class and specifiy it in the tooltip initialization, it doesnt round the corners. I'm assuming there is some css priority conflict, but I am completely new to css and not sure of its underworkings yet.

I really just need round corners.

```
.ui-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
    background: #f9a235;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 6px 0px; 
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 25px;
  }
```

Comment: Have you given the tooltip any height or width?

Comment: put !important after your border-radius and see if that helps

Comment: I have not given it any height or width, I will try adding !important

Comment: We also need to see some HTML and more CSS. It would be best if you could post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with an example.

Comment: take a look here: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style

Comment: [Border-radius isn't well supported in some older versions of IE](http://caniuse.com/border-radius). Short of that you need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Help us to help you.

Comment: I apologize for the shortness, I'll see if I can replicate the issue in a test application, and provide a better example. The HTML for this is just 2 test <p> elements, with the tooltips being created dynamically by a javascript library I am writing

Comment: You might consider using Bootstrap's tooltip. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Answer (score 3):

What's not working about your current implementation?

### [Working Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/5cAH2/)

This should be doing the trick:

```css
.ui-tooltip {
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

#### Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Make sure to check for browser compatibility as this won't work in IE8:
http://caniuse.com/border-radius

Comment: This works in my browser, as do many other examples. Its a rather large struts app with a lot of moving parts, with this not really being my knowledge area. From what I understand, it SHOULD just work, which is why im so lost.