# Render Highchart with dynamic ID in jQuery tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to render a highchart chart to a jquery tooltip. I also want to pass the ID of the element being hovered, so that it is passed directly to highcharts as a variable to the renderTo argument. Right now I cannot get this to work. Please click here for the [JS fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/yx27xf7h/4/)

My code is as follows.

```
  $(document).tooltip({

    open: function() {

    var widget = $(this).data("ui-tooltip");
    var widget = $(widget.element[0]).attr("id")

      Highcharts.chart({
        chart: {
          renderTo: widget,
          type: 'bar'
        },
```

**Edit**

I need the ID of the hovered element. At least I think I do. The reason is that I need to feed an array specific to this ID to the highchart function. Also, I may want to hover a class and generate the graph to a div with a prefix. Here is another [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/3r2kkeqy/) with pseudo code.

**HTML**

```
<p>
 <label for="age">Your age:</label>
 <input id="age" title="<div class='container' id='containerX'>
 <div id='chart_containerX' style='width:500px;height:500px;background:red'>
 </div>
</div>"/>
    </p>
    <p>Hover the field to see the tooltip.</p>
```

**JScript**

```
$(function() {
  $(".container").tooltip({

  <pseudo> get ID and generate array so that it can be passed to highcharts </pseudo>
  <pseudo> get ID and add 'chart_' prefix so that it can be passed to renderTo </pseudo>


    open: function(event, ui) {
      ui.tooltip.highcharts({
        data: { <<'array specific to this chart'>>},
        chart: {
          renderTo: <<chart_container (with prefix!)>>
          type: 'bar'
        },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect example to learn to check the documentation carefully and also to debug.

First, you don't need the element ID to render Highcharts to an element. [As documentation says](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart), you can do this:

```
element.highcharts({/* options */});
```

And second, have you tried to see if your `widget` variable actually contains something? If you do a `console.log(widget)`, you will see that the console outputs undefined, and if you do `console.log($(this).data("ui-tooltip"))` you see that the console logs the document, not the widget element. This is a perfect point to [check the documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#event-open) and see that the `open` event receives a second `ui` argument with the actual tooltip element, being it a jQuery element so no need for `$(ui.tooltip)` but directly access `ui.tooltip`.

Now with all this info you can do this:

```
open: function(event, ui) {
  ui.tooltip.highcharts({
```

Which comes into this: https://jsfiddle.net/yx27xf7h/5/

**IMPORTANT:** You need to destroy the Highchart when the widget closes or you will end with a **memory leak** (Insert dramatic ♪DUN DUN DUUUN♫ music here).

EDIT: If you want to use a container element, is better to avoid adding IDs as IDs must be unique in the entire webpage so you must find a way to create a unique ID each time and that's adding extra code when you can avoid it. The less code for the same task, the better.

When working with containers that are created and destroyed on the fly is better to work with references and ways to gather them as references inside their parent containers, for example doing `.class` or using data attributes, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/yx27xf7h/6/

Comment: Jorge, very much appreciate the time and effort you have put into this. I am not sure the solution addresses my need. Please look at the edit above. I think I really need to pass on the ID as requested.

Comment: @Noobster Well, if you need the id you can do `ui.tooltip.attr("id")`, but I really don't see the needs to pass the id to `renderTo` when you can do it the default way, without ids.

Comment: What if I need to pass it not directly to the containing, hoverable div, but to a nested div where the id is the parent id with a prefix? e.g. chart_{parent ID}

Comment: @Noobster Oh I see your problem now. Then I think is better to add a class to the chart container, like this `<div class='chart' style='width:500px;height:500px;background:red'>` or even use `data` attributes like this (So no CSS is involved) `<div data-chart='chart' style='width:500px;height:500px;background:red'>` and get that container with a `find`, like this: if class is used: `ui.tooltip.find(".chart")` or if data is used: `ui.tooltip.find("[data-chart='chart']")`, so you will end with: `ui.tooltip.find("[data-chart='chart']").highcharts({/* blah */})`

Comment: @Noobster Going to edit the answer with info like this

Comment: @Noobster Edited. Note that the chart has a white background, so you won't see your red background. You must change the style of the chart to have a transparent or red background. The chart is actually rendered inside the container as you can see by the blue border.

Comment: I am not sure I follow, Jorge. I need to access the the id (or in this case 'data-chart') dynamically from the tooltip hover. I may have 50 of them on my page, each time with a different id. Right now ui.tooltip.find("[data-chart='chart']") is static.

Comment: Ok, let's see. The `ui.tooltip.find("[data-chart='chart']")` is not that static because it finds elements inside the tooltip container. You may have 50 elements in your page, but only one inside each tooltip so it will only find one element. You are not saying to search on the entire webpage, but just inside the tooltip just created, the very only that only has 1 `data-chart` element because the other elements are inside other tooltips. Share a Fiddle with multiple elements and I'll try my best to help you and also optimize your page while you learn more things about this :P

Comment: @Noobster Hi Noobster. How are you doing?